# Why does iOs Safari show full size of background-image?

Tags: ios, css, background-image, background-size

I'm working on a site where you have some boxes with background-images as thumbnails. I have to use background-image because the CMS we are working on is pretty old-dated and the client won't change (mon€y is the main-problem).

i figured out a strange behavior in the iOs Safari on the iPad2 & iPhone5 (latest iOS) and don't know why.

Here's my code:

```css
a img,
.thumb,
figcaption,
a:hover .thumb {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -ms-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.thumb {
  height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
figcaption {
  background-color: #b61910;
  background-color: rgba(182, 25, 16, .85);
  position: absolute;
  height: 39px;
  bottom: 35px;
  color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
figcaption h3 {
  font-style: normal;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 0 0 5px;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
}
a:hover h3 {
  transform: translate3d(0, -20%, 0);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
a:hover figcaption {
  height: 5px;
}
a:hover .thumb {
  background-size: 120% 120%;
  opacity: .8
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <figure class="thumb" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/output/food-h-c-850-890-7.jpg)">
          <figcaption>
            <h3>Product-Title</h3>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

On my Desktop it shows the whole image but on iOS it looks like it shows the original size inside the thumbnail-box.
How can i solve this problem?

Any help would be great :)
Thanks

moesphemie

Answer (score -1):

Maybe? https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/full-page-backgrounds-on-ios-background-size-cover/

Code:

```
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```